# Binding on Elements of an ObservableCollection only change when Page is reloaded

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-8.1

I am programming a Windows 8.1 App using C#/XAML as well as the MVVM-Light Toolkit.

In my program there is a Schedule that consists of 3 components:

- a GridView with 5 elements for Monday, Tuesday, ....
- a ListView with x elements each showing the start- and end-time of
  the current period. x depends on the number of period the user chose
  for his schedule to have.
- a GridView with 5*x elements that represent the places for the events
  set by the user.

These 3 components are again inside a FlipView to enable multiple Schedules.
I enabled this in code via the following objects:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }

    public ScheduleComponentSettings ScheduleComponentSettings { get; set; }    
    public ScheduleComponents ScheduleComponents { get; set; }
} 


public class ScheduleComponents
{
    public ObservableCollection<WeekDay> WeekDayItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FreePeriod> FreePeriodItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PeriodTime> PeriodTimesItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LessonTime> LessonTimesItems { get; set; }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have an ObservableCollection of the Schedule class:

```
public ObservableCollection<Schedule> ScheduleComponentsList
{
    get
    {
        return _ScheduleComponentsList;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_ScheduleComponentsList == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(ScheduleWeekListPropertyName);
        _ScheduleComponentsList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(ScheduleWeekListPropertyName);
    }
}
```

The FlipView and its elements bind to that as follows (this is ofc. shortened to show only the   ItemsSources):

```
<FlipView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Main.ScheduleComponentsList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <GridView                  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleComponents.WeekDayItems}"/>
             <ListView                  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleComponents.PeriodTimesItems}"/>
             <GridView                  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleComponents.FreePeriodItems}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Now here is the problem:
When I change a property on an element inside the FreePeriodItems or even when I replace the collection completely, the View only updates when I reload the entire Page. Same for all the other properties I update in one on the ScheduleComponents. 
This does not occur however when I change the ScheduleComponentList itself. When I add items to it for example they are automatically being updated in the view.

Now I am sitting on the problem for ages now.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not occur however when I change the ScheduleComponentList itself. When I add items to it for example they are automatically being updated in the view.

That's exactly how `ObservableCollection<T>` works. It raises events only when the list itself changes, when you add or remove elements:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.
>
> *from [ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

To make it work implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your `WeekDay`, `FreePeriod`, `PeriodTime` and `LessonTime`. When it's done you'll get event not only when collection changes but also when any of the items that already are part of collection is modified.

Comment: Hey, your answer seems correct and I see your point. However I am still pretty new to this and don't know where exactly to implement that. Would you please show me that by posting an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: There is an example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey, do you mean the line: public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>? If yes I would have the problem of SQLite - which I use for my Databse - not knowing about that property ...

Comment: All classes you're binding with should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It has nothing to do with `ObservableCollection<T>`, that's the rule.